# Replace variable with query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

I am pretty new to using mysql and variables in php.

I have this code

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `forum_threads` (`name`, `byid`, `cid`,
`content`, `time`, `lastreplied_time`, `lastreplier_id`) VALUES
('{$title}', '{$uid}', '{$cid}', '{$content}', '" . time() . "', '" .
time() . "', '{$uid}');") or die(mysql_error());
```

In my php file, I want `byid` to be the value of `id` in my table `forum_users`. So can I replace `{$uid}` with something that will get the value from `forum_users`. Because I don't think {$uid} is working correct.

I found this code

```
/* Non-existant forum account */ final public function
createForumAccount($uid) {
    $getHabboUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM
        `users` WHERE `id` = '{$uid}' LIMIT 1");
```

I assume that the function of that code is to get the `{$uid}` equal the `id` from the `users` table, I want to make the `{$uid}` to equal the id from the `forum_users` table.

Then I found this code:

```
final public function getUserData($uid, $var) {
    if($this->checkForAccount($uid) == true) {
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT `{$var}` FROM `forum_users` WHERE `uid` = '{$uid}' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
        return mysql_result($check, 0);
    }
}
```

That code wants the `{$uid}` to equal forum_users `id`. And that is exactly what I want, but it doesn't equal that, it equals the `id` from the `users` table instead, I assume it might collide with eachother or something.

How can I solve this? Can I replace `{$uid}` in my first code, so `byid` is selected instantly from `forum_users`? Can I make a new variable that equals `forum_users.id`?

Comment: I dont know where and how you found a tutorial on using `mysql_*` functions but even taking a look at the documentation of `mysql_connect()` you will see a **big red box saying it is depreciated to use it**. So either learn PDO or mysqli, and than get back to us.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this sql query makes no sense. However I am also not sure your question either. If your wanting to change `byid` to `id` in your table then you must alter the table. But here is a cleaner version of your sql query.
try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO forum_threads SET name=\"".$title."\",byid=\"".$uid."\",cid=\"".$cid."\",content=\"".$content."\",time=\"".time()."\",lastreplied_time=\"".time()."\",lastreplier_id=\"".$uid."\" WHERE id=\"".$uid."\" LIMIT 1") or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
//You Change ID to byid
```

to change byid to ID

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `forum_threads` CHANGE `byid` `id` int NOT NULL")or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
// this will change the column byid to id
```

Just Remember `Mysql_connect()` and `mysql API` are old and not used after php 7 so start to learn `mysqli api`

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: I don't think you understand, you see "byid" in this code? **mysql_query("INSERT INTO `forum_threads` (`name`, `byid`, `cid`, `content`, `time`, `lastreplied_time`, `lastreplier_id`) VALUES ('{$title}', '{$uid}', '{$cid}', '{$content}', '" . time() . "', '" . time() . "', '{$uid}');") or die(mysql_error());** when that query is runned "byid" equals "{$uid}" and I {$uid} equals users "id" in my users table. I want byid to equal forum_users "id" in that query

Comment: So $uid does it already have the value from forum_users / id? Or you want to assign that to uid? Is this a logged in check? Or do we know what specific id from forum_users?